# Ways to code Java Listeners

Tags: java, listener, actionlistener, eventhandler

Well I know several ways to add a listener to Swing Components, but I'd like to know WHICH is the best option on each case:

1. One component, one action, example: a single button that calls an event to do x.
   Reading Oracle docs I've found that the best way for that one is using `EventHandler` like this:

   ```
   component.addActionListener((ActionListener)EventHandler.create(ActionListener.class, frame, "methodToCall"));
   ```
2. Several components, one action, example: 10 buttons for the same event.
   ???
3. One component, several actions, example: 1 button that calls x event, y event and z event to do different stuff.
   ???

Comment: **best** is almost always a red flag in a question as it is **off-topic: opinion based**

Comment: Thanks pal i couldn't find other posts related to my needs :)

Comment: @GhostCat well i solved this long time ago without stackoverflow users help (sadly) so i'm not sure what to do with this post right now, what should i do?

Comment: @GotyMetal Two options: you accept the answer ... or you delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

**If** there are performance problems within your application, most likely they will not be coming from how you implement your listeners (unless you do real stupid things in there). ("if" meaning: don't starting fixing performance problems until you have clear indication+analysis that they exist and where they are coming from).

So my probably unexpected answer: don't worry about performance. Of course, use common sense to avoid things that cost performance for no good reason; but instead: worry about a clear and solid design.

If your performance is 100% good; but your design is only 50% good; your product will become harder and harder to maintain and extend. In other words: focus on concepts like "single responsibility principle" or "don't repeat yourself" (which you can google to learn more about them).

Besides: if there are performance problems within your program; they are easier to fix when the whole thing has a sound design.

Comment: I don't have performance issues on my applications, i'm just asking for the future to make things better :)